# Is there a way to change url leading into scrollIntoView function?

Tags: javascript

I created a menu and one of the items in menu is working as a scrollIntoView option, but when I go to some other page and press that item in menu scrollIntoView can't be finished because there is no div to scroll to...
So i was wondering is there a way to make that item do 2 things on other pages, like changing the page into scrollIntoView function ?

```
window.onload=function(){
  var el = document.getElementById('uslugeMeni');
  el.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    console.log("Hello world!");
            var elmnt = document.getElementById("uslugeContainer");
            elmnt.scrollIntoView();
        });
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a code example on jsfiddle or similar?

Comment: emm, what about use js control it？when `document.body.scrollHeight <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)`, change menu's position

Comment: @trebleCode I added the code I use, but it's not working if there is no div with id "uslugeContainer", so I was wondering how to combine some href to get the user to the page with actual div + scrollIntoView